# Capture serial console text from a Hyper-V guest

Tags: hyper-v, console

I have a Hyper-V guest running CentOS 7. When the guest panics and prints a kernel Oops message, is it possible to capture the text written to the console? Note that the message is not written to dmesg, and thus, cannot be retrieved on the next reboot.

Comment: This looks related to [How to redirect a Hyper-V COM port named pipe to a file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/434110)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a serial port to a VM, create one (or more) named pipes in PowerShell. Note that PowerShell must be "run as administrator" for this to work. The example here uses a VM named `dv0`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VMComPort -VMName dv0

VMName Name  Path
------ ----  ----
dv0    COM 1
dv0    COM 2

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-VMComPort -VMName dv0 -Path \\.\pipe\dv0-com1 -Number 1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VMComPort -VMName dv0

VMName Name  Path
------ ----  ----
dv0    COM 1 \\.\pipe\dv0-com1
dv0    COM 2
```

In the Linux VM, add the console setting via grubby for `COM1` (a.k.a. `ttyS0`):

```
[root@dv0 ~]# grubby --args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0=115200" --update-kernel `grubby --default-kernel`
```

PuTTY can capture the output from the named pipe. In the session options, use Serial for the destination, `\\.\pipe\dv0-com1` for the Serial line, and 115200 for the Speed to match the Linux console settings. Because the named pipes are created as Administrator, PuTTY must also be "run as administrator".